# How To Approach Authentication In My Web App?  JSF2 + Spring3 + GlassFish3 + Hibernate

Tags: authentication, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'm building a new web app from scratch for a client.

The tools are JSF2, PrimeFaces, Spring3, GlassFish3, Hibernate.

I have a basic web app working fine.  Now I have to put authentication in.

My first thought was to hack together a login form that sets a session variable and have a phase listener check for the session variable and redirect to "logged out" when the variable is invalid or too old.  But that sounds like a *total hack*.

I've googled, but I don't really know where to start.  What's the REAL way of doing authentication in my web app on my platform?

Can anyone help, or point me to a tutorial, or the relevant documentation?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

rh

Answer (score 1):

The phaselistener you thought about is one of the solution in JSF.  Another solution is Spring security.  If you are not thinking about any of these, you can try Servlet filter